# Global replace in a regexp expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a Javascript regexp replace function that allows me to replace every instance of some tags delimited by squared brackets with an arbitrary string.

```
function TestTags() {
    var url = "test1=[A1]&test2=[A1]";
    result = url.replace('\[A1\]', 'test');
    console.log("result = " + result);
}
```

This works fine only for the first occurrence:

```
result = test1=test&test2=[A1]
```

I know it's pretty silly but I haven't be able to set the 'g' parameter to make it global. Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a g to it and use the `//` syntax:

```
url.replace(/\[A1\]/g, 'test');
```

Comment: thanks Joseph :D I was sure it was something silly. With your quick answer you've been brilliant and helpful.